# How to set up build.gradle and gradle.properties in cordova(6.0.0) app give me a example

Tags: cordova, gradle, build.gradle

I am creating cordova application with gradle build, Does anybody know what all changes have to do in `build.gradle` and what are the fields to be add in `gradle.properties` please give a example

https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CB-11109

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As of cordova-android@4.0.0, Cordova android projects are built using Gradle by default. Setting gradle properties and extending build.gradle are explained in detail in offical [cordova documentation](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/guide/platforms/android/index.html#configuring-gradle)

Comment: Yes already went through those Docs but I am bit confused, can you give me the example file for gradle.properties and what should be there in build-extras.gradle and build.gradle @Gandhi

Comment: @NaveenBannikoppa once you build android platform, build,gradle file is automatically generated. Also if you wanna add gradle,properties, you can do it inside platform/android folder & set properties as mentioned in the documentation. Still not sure what exaclty is your problem.

Comment: I am getting wrong app-version with that build.gradle(18 instead of 1) and we cant edit build.gradle directly, my question is how to edit build.gradle and if I edit what should be there in build-extars.gradle. And mainly dont know what are the properties to be set in gradle.properties and how to set. I am new to mobile application  development if you explain me cleanly it will be very helpful.@Gandhi

Comment: @NaveenBannikoppa could you post the complete error trace?

Comment: I have created Cordova android application with version 1 it worked till today, want to launch second version of the app from now with new feature. Changed the version in config.xml version 2, and created apk signed version with existing key-store and key password. Uploaded new version of apk to live server(not app-store)but apk is not downloading , when I gone through the configuration of the project it was totally wrong and am facing difficulty in finding the solution. And my  questions are configuration project and creating apk.@Gandhi

Comment: I updated my question with jira link you can check there@Gandi

Comment: new version of apk is not getting downloaded from existing app @Gandhi